# Cannot `import static` static nested class?

Tags: java, import, compilation, static, package

I have a class `A` with a static nested class inside it called `B`:

```
import static A.B.*;

class A {
    static class B {
        static int x;
        static int y;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I want to static import everything in `B`, but it wont work:

```
$ javac A.java
A.java:1: package A does not exist
import static A.B.*;
               ^
A.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable x
location: class A
        System.out.println(x);
                           ^
2 errors
```

Why?

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This won't work if `A` is in the default package. However, you could add a package declaration:

```
package mypackage;
```

and use

```
import static mypackage.A.B.*;
```

The static import syntax from from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3) is given:

> SingleStaticImportDeclaration:
>       import static *TypeName* . Identifier ;

where *TypeName* is required to be [full qualified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7).

In [Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) the `static import` syntax is given with package name included:

```
import static mypackage.MyConstants.*;
```

[It is recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to use `static` imports very sparingly.

Comment: From JLS, it would seem that the class TypeName needs to be fully qualified. Judging from this, the compiler requires the convention of a package name to be present, probably to avoid ambiguity of class usage

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
import <the-package-for-the-class-A>.A.B.*;
```

If A is in the default package, this will fail.

Last, it's not a good practice to import `*`. Just import only the things that you need, in this case - `import static <the-package-for-the-class-A>.A.B.x;` if you're gonna use only the `x` variable.

Comment: "it's not a good practice to import *" Even if it's from the same file?

Comment: what? I do use the imports, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question