# How do I use java reflection to instantiate a class that cannot be imported?

Tags: java, junit, reflection

I'm writing JUnit tests to test code in another package which must match a pre-defined specification. The code under test must contains a nested class which I want to instantiate inside the test package -- it's not possible to import this class because it's nested (and so not visible outside the original package).

E.g. package structure:

```
packageA
-> ClassA
     -> packageA.ClassA$ClassB

tests
-> ClassATest
```

I need to test a method in ClassA that takes an instance of ClassB as an argument.

I'm currently using reflection to get from `ClassA` (which I can import) to `ClassB` [`cls.getDeclaredClasses`]. I can then get a constructor for `ClassB` [`cls.getDeclaredConstructor`] and thus create a new instance of `ClassB` using the found constructor [`constructor.newInstance`]. This call to `constructor.newInstance` returns an `Object`.

How do I get from the returned `Object` type to something of the correct `ClassB` type so that I can pass it into the `ClassA` method under test?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly It is possible to import a nested class. [Cannot `import static` static inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595847/cannot-import-static-static-inner-class)

This is sounds as a bad design that you are forced to use a reflection for tests.

Because you have got `Object` from reflection and you don't have a type accessible, you should also use reflection again to pass it into the method.

Comment: Yes, it's not an elegant design, but those constraints exist due to the slightly artificial nature of this problem (testing for the purposes of hitting the spec, not to test that it works).

Comment: Could you expand on this please, an example would be super helpful: "Because you have got Object from reflection and you don't have a type accessible, you should also use reflection again to pass it into the method." Thanks.

Comment: "Firstly It is possible to import a nested class. Cannot `import static` static inner class?" -- The linked question is importing the inner class from within the *same class*, I want to import from a different class in another package. I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: @Saff As simple example `import java.util.Map.Entry;` works and has been done a thousand times in a thousand projects all over the world.

Comment: @Saff Not sure how to expand it. You said, you are using reflection to find and call a constructor. Just do the same to find and call a method with the created object as a parameter. If you show the code I could try expanding it, but currently I don't know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Holger Urgh. Thanks for pointing this out. On closer examination I'd managed to miscase the import! Thanks both. One puzzle solved at least.